# THREE.js OrbitControls not working when using Typescript (Working with javascript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, three.js

I have this small project written in javascript (one long file) and now i must move it to typescript (using DDD). Now the question is the following, the code is working when running the angular calls the javascript file. But when i try to use the newly created typescript with the same code, the orbit controls does not work at all, i am not able to move the scene like i used to using the javascript file.

in the **javascript** the order i use is the following:

```js
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas, antialias: true});
    // some renderer properties

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, window.innerWidth / innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    // camera position and lookat defined here

    const orbitControls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    orbitControls.update();
```

in the **typescript**, in the **main.ts** file we create the renderer, the canvas, and the camera, using an classes for the rendere, orbitControls...:

```js
  private canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
  private evRenderer: EvRenderer; // simplified
  private evCamera: EvCamera;


  async ngOnInit() {
    // some project related await calls

    this.canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
    this.evRenderer = new Renderer(this.canvas);
    this.evScene = new EvScene();
    this.evCamera = new EvCamera();

    this.orbitControls = new EvOrbitControls(this.evCamera.camera, this.evRenderer.renderer);
```

now the EvOrbitControls class:

```js
export class EvOrbitControls {

  private orbitControls: OrbitControls;
  private evCamera: EvCamera;
  private evRenderer: EvRenderer;

  constructor(evCamera: EvCamera, evRenderer: EvRenderer) {
    this.camera = evCamera;
    this.renderer = evRenderer;
    this.orbitControls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
    this.orbitControls.update();
  }

  enable() {
    this.orbitControls.enabled = true;
  }

  disable() {
    this.orbitControls.enabled = false;
  }
}
```

This is obviously not over and improvements to code are needed, but still we can not use the orbitcontrols. The Scene appears correctly, with the objects inserted in it (like in the javascript).

**Also**:
 The project is in **Angular 8**. 
 The import of orbitcontrols is the following:

```js
import {OrbitControls} from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
```

as by suggested in the npm site: 
*"three-js exposes real modules now via three/examples/jsm/... for example to import Orbit, do import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'"*

**Also**:
The **EvRenderer** and **EvCamera** just have a private atribute THREE.WebGlRenderer and a THREE.PerspectiveCamera, respectively, and the atributes are set in the constructor. the atributes are the same as in the javascript file.

I've tried other imports too, like the the one in the [npm site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-orbitcontrols-ts), which has 3 years since late update, and does not work, the problem remains the same.

The code gives no errors/warnings, just the orbit controls does not work.

Any help or suggestion will be helpfull :)

**EDIT:** Without the class wrapper as mentioned by @Don McCurdy the apllication stays like this, simply as this:

```js
  private canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
  private evRenderer: EvRenderer;
  private evCamera: EvCamera;
  private orbitControls: OrbitControls;


  async ngOnInit() {
    // some project related await calls

    this.canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
    this.evRenderer = new Renderer(this.canvas);
    this.evScene = new EvScene();
    this.evCamera = new EvCamera();

    this.orbitControls = new OrbitControls(this.evCamera.camera, this.evRenderer.renderer);
    }
```

Comment: In the JS version you use OrbitControls directly, while in TS you wrap it with a custom object... could you create a simpler example without that wrapper? There's a bit too much going on here for someone to reproduce your problem without a demo.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy tried to simplify the code, i dont know if its because its wrapped or if its something threejs does not entirely support from typescript or even angular. cant solve the issue, all seems the same, but is not working

Comment: Your import should be correct as we're using [the exact same import](https://github.com/makimenko/angular-template-for-threejs/blob/15e13e8ad3e18187804ba9b2877c78b42d2808f2/projects/atft/src/lib/control/orbit-controls.component.ts#L2) in [our project with Angular & Three.js](https://github.com/makimenko/angular-template-for-threejs). I remember there was some weird wrong mouse offset at the beginning. Could it be that? I forgot how I fixed that. Feel free to browse our source code.

Comment: @ComFreek good project, i dont think its the same problem, i mean, i have drag controls also set and even tho i cant drag objects (the 'Hoveron' is actually working), the mouse correctly identifies them in the scene, but for some reason, the orbitcontrols are not working (same for dragControls)

Comment: @DiogoSoares Then I think it's hard to debug over wire. Can you set up an online Angular fiddle (preferred) or a GitHub repo of a minimal reproducing example?